# Вывод битового кода числа

Tags: битовые-операции, c++

Как сделать, чтобы после ввода числа, программа вывела его битовый код? Прочитал про битовые операции, но все же реализовать саму программу не смог

Comment: Почитайте о битовых операциях.

Comment: прочитал. Но там такого нет, там о самих процессах пишется. Вы можете мне наглядный пример написать, чтобы я с ним разобрался уже. Думаю так пойму.

Comment: И не должно быть. Там описаны необходимые кирпичики для построения программы. Вы уже давно тут задаете вопросы по С++, а элементарных вещей не научились делать.

Comment: не думаю что битовый код - элементарная вещь. Да и с тех пор как я начал задавать вопросы, я развиваю себя. Читаю и практикуюсь. Хоть и мелкими шагами, но все же двигаюсь. И часто я учусь и понимаю на примерах. Вот почему и просил от вас

Comment: это элементарная простейшая вещь

Comment: не хотите помогать, могли бы и не отвечать!

Answer (score 6):

```
int i, N;
N = 1234;
i = 65536;

while (true) {
    if (N & i)        // битовое И - в данном случае вернет 2^i - если i-ый бит 1
        printf("1");
    else
        printf("0"); 
    if (i == 1)       // мы рассмотрели младший бит - выходим из цикла
        break;
    i >>= 1;         // битовый сдвиг, запись числа смещается на один бит
}                    // аналогично делению на 2, но быстрее.
```

Как вариант.

Вариаций много, изучите битовые операции: [wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Comment: а что тут N и i означают??? И если не трудно, объясни мне строку: if(N&i) printf("1");

Comment: > объясните мне строку: if(N&i)

По приведенной ссылке на википедию смотрите таблицу в разделе "в языках программирования".

Comment: ты можешь мне написать программу, которая будет выводить битовый код числа? Я так а то не понимаю. Я знаю у тебя всегда бывает очень понятный код, с комментариями особенно. Если не трудно, можешь показать? А то я читаю читаю и не вникаю никак. Может так пойму

Comment: 65536= двоичное 10000000000000000, т.е. это 16-й бит если считать от 0

N&i делает побитовую операцию "И", получется если в N этот бит установлен - результат не 0, иначе 0.

Далее идёт сдвиг и в следующий раз анализируем 15-й бит и т.д.

Answer (score 5):

Странно, что [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) никто не вспомнил:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>

int main() {
    int num = 32;
    std::cout << std::bitset<sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT>(num) << "\n";
}
```

> 00000000000000000000000000100000

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef unsigned short ushort;
ushort num = 34;
for(int i = 15; i >= 0; --i) // short 16 бит (00000000 00000000)
   std::cout << ((num >> i) & 1) << " "; // проходимся по битам и выводим через пробел
```

Для этого необходимо выучить побитовые операции, это совсем несложно - информации в интернете полным полно

Comment: Почему 15, а не `(sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT) - 1`?

Comment: @VladD, http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1347020.html

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/IHMlWD

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename number> char * tobinary(number x, char *buf)
{
    number q;
    char *p=buf;

    if((number)~0<0)
    {
        *(p++) = '0' + (x<0);
        q = (number)1 << ((sizeof(number)<<3) - 2);
    }
    else
        q = (number)1 << ((sizeof(number)<<3) - 1);

    for(; q; q>>=1)
        *(p++) = x & q ? '1' : '0';

    *p = 0;

    return buf;
}

#define POSVAL 7
#define NEGVAL -7

int main(void)
{
    char temp[128];

    #define TEST(type,val) do { type x=val; puts(tobinary(x, temp)); } while(0)

    TEST(char, POSVAL);
    TEST(unsigned char, POSVAL);
    TEST(signed char, POSVAL);

    TEST(unsigned short, POSVAL);
    TEST(signed short, POSVAL);

    TEST(unsigned, POSVAL);
    TEST(signed, POSVAL);

    TEST(unsigned long, POSVAL);
    TEST(signed long, POSVAL);

    TEST(unsigned long long, POSVAL);
    TEST(signed long long, POSVAL);

    TEST(char, NEGVAL);
    TEST(unsigned char, NEGVAL);
    TEST(signed char, NEGVAL);

    TEST(unsigned short, NEGVAL);
    TEST(signed short, NEGVAL);

    TEST(unsigned, NEGVAL);
    TEST(signed, NEGVAL);

    TEST(unsigned long, NEGVAL);
    TEST(signed long, NEGVAL);

    TEST(unsigned long long, NEGVAL);
    TEST(signed long long, NEGVAL);

    #undef TEST

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Хм, а почему `sizeof(number)<<3`, а не `sizeof(number) * CHAR_BIT`? А вдруг байт не восьмибитный?

Comment: А ещё есть http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned

Answer (score 0):

Была как то задача, в которой необходимо было заполнить массив от 0 до а битами каждого числа.

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        int row = 1 << a, row1;
        int digit[row][a];
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        row1 = i;
            for(int j = 0; j < a; j++){
                digit[i][j] = (row1 >> (a - j - 1)) & 1;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < a; j++){
                cout << digit[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```