# Ввести из стандартного потока число типа signed int. Вывести его битовое представление

Tags: c, алгоритм, битовые-операции

Ввести из стандартного потока число типа signed int. 
Вывести его битовое представление.
может кто нибудь помочь? или объяснить суть?

Вот моя версия:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    signed int x, i;
    printf("Введите число:\n");
    scanf_s("%i", &x);
    for (i = sizeof(x) * 8 - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%d", (x >> i) & 1);
    }
}
```

Когда я залил ее на сайт проверяться, мне выдало миллион ошибок.

Comment: Наверное, тот кто задал, тот и сможет объяснить суть. Под словом "помочь" вы подразумеваете написание кода за вас?

Comment: я учусь на 1 курсе, нам дали эту лабораторную. Преподаватель думаю что мы это проходили, но я этого не проходил в школе, хочу чтобы хотя бы натолкнули на мысль как делать.

Comment: В чем конкретно вопрос? Ввод? Проверка определенного бита? Вывод?

Comment: Ввести из стандартного потока число типа signed int. 
Вывести его битовое представление. вот как звучит задание.

Comment: Вы умеете писать `Hello World`? Знакомы с функцией `scanf`?

Comment: вот мне интересно, а метка `метапрограммирование` тут зачем?) И кстати, получение знакового бита числа это UB или нет?

Comment: да, Hello world умею. с scanf знаком

Comment: а на 2 делить умеете? а циклы писать?

Comment: @petrucho `char *itoa(int num, char *str, int radix)`

Comment: @pavel ну не смешите, на первом курсе не так решают задачи подобные

Comment: @teran ну я бы битсет предложил, но это с++

Comment: @teran у нас было всего 1 вводное занятие, поэтому я и не понял. а сдать эту прогу нужно до завтра

Comment: @pavel от него там хотят запрограммировать перевод из десятичной в двоичную путем обычного деления

Comment: @pavel нам говорили на си писать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/99079/178988 - поставил бы дубликатом, но там плюсы, а тут - нет...

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned int x;
scanf("%d",&x);
while (x) printf("%d",x&1),x>>=1;
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66629/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel-------signed-in).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> scanf_s("%i", &x);
> ```

> залил ее на сайт проверяться

Попробуй

```
scanf("%i", &x);
```

В остальном код верный (https://ideone.com/KWOevP), если в задаче не оговаривается отбрасывание лидирующих нулей.

Comment: 3 балла из 5 получил. чего-то не хватает. по этому коду;  https://ideone.com/M6DwkH

Comment: @petrucho, я же в комментарии к тому ответу написал, что порядок битов неверный.

Comment: я понял, ну я не смог их исправить.

Comment: @petrucho, твоё решение правильнее того.

Comment: @qwetiy мы это решение делали с одногрупником, заливали на сайт проверяться, выдало 0 баллов из 5