# Функция sprintf

Tags: c, алгоритм

Имеется целочисленный массив , где лежат уже переведенные десятичные числа в двоичные.Но мне нужно,чтобы эти двоичные числа были в восьмибитной записи , то есть с одним или с несколькими  незначащими  нулями в начале.И всё это перенести из целочисленного массива в строку , добавляя незначащие нули в начало двоичного числа.

Не нашёл понятного мануала по sprintf. Соорудилось нечто такое:

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        sprintf(num2+strlen(num2),"%d",A1[j]);
```

Вроде делает строку из двоичных чисел.
Вот только как сосчитать , сколько незначащих нулей нужно добавить и как это сделать ?
Пытался сделать так:

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    sprintf(num2+strlen(num2),"%c","%d", '0',A1[j]);
```

Но выводит мусор, скорее всего из-за  num2+strlen(num2)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/565940/178988

Comment: Вы хотите распечатать эти числа побитно? И сколько незначащих бит надо оставлять?

Comment: @avp,одно или два

Comment: А что думаете печатать, если самый старший (31-й) бит это единичка?

Comment: @avp,честно - не знаю, я пока другой реализацией думаю , вот такой : int u, N,k=0;
 N = 13;
 u = 256;
 putchar('\n');
 while (true) {
  if (N & u)        
   num2[k++] = '1';
  else
   num2[k++] = '0';
  if (u == 1)       
   break;
  u >>= 1;  
 }

Comment: но там лишний 9-ый бит.UPD вроде получилось

Comment: Понятно, что `sprintf(num2+strlen(num2),"%c","%d", '0',A1[j]);` выводит мусор - вы же хотите вывести только `%c`, и передаете для одного этого спецификатора целых три параметра :)  Вот так оно как-то надежнее:`sprintf(num2+strlen(num2),"%c%d", '0',A1[j]);`

Comment: Может быть человек говорил о 8-меричной записи числа ? там обычно идёт два нуля вначале (`00`), а в 16-ричной - `0x`. Ну и вывод: `sprintf(buf, "00%o", myNumber);`